# Push after two jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I use gerrit + Jenkins. And I have two jobs:

1. build,
2. tests.

And I want to push commits in remote/master after build-ok and tests-ok, if build-ok and tests-failed commit will not push. But now my commits push if build-ok only, and No matter what state in tests.

Comment: how do you use gerrit trigger? just downstream sequence jobs or blocking downstream jobs?

Comment: @Stanjer I have two jobs: 1st Build, 2nd Check. And now I use "Build Trigger" option in the 2nd job called Check. I marked "Build after other projects are built", "Projects to watch" - my 1st job called Build, and marked "Trigger only if build is stable".

Comment: Is pushing your commits a post build step in your build job ? then what your are getting above is expected.

Comment: @prudviraj, yes. But I want to publish my commits only if two jobs will be stable there are build  and tests.

Comment: If that is the case then make your test job run only when build job is succeeded , use trigger for that and create a post build step in test job for pushing your  commits , this will confirm that you commit happens only after executing both jobs , Important thing here is if tests fail , your test job will fail at build step and will not go to post build step so making sure  push of your commit skipped.

Comment: @prudviraj Ok, you are right, but how does it connected with gerrit plugin?

Comment: you have a down stream job 'check' (which has test cases to be executed) , it will run only when  upstream job (build which has your gerrit push commit section) is succeed , is this you current set up or i am missing something here ..!!

Comment: @prudviraj I have "Build" job with "Post-build actions", "Check". I want to use gerrit for publish commits in remote/master branch if "Build" has status OK and "Check" has status OK.